# Can't block specific IP address with iptables, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, iptables, fail2ban

I'm trying to troubleshoot Fail2ban recognizing our http-get-dos trigger, but not actually banning the offending host. I can see it adding entries to iptables rules, but they don't have any affect.

So I tried to manually ban a host, and I cant get that to work either.

I'm trying to drop all traffic from a specific host. I inserted a DROP rule, and appended a DROP rule, so they bookend everything. I've X'ed out the ip address of the host I'm trying to ban. This host can still connect to my web server, and get web pages.

I must be missing something stupid. Here's the `iptables -nvL` output:

```
$ sudo iptables -nvL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 6226 packets, 31M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       XX.XX.XX.XX         0.0.0.0/0
85222 7764K fail2ban-xmlrpc  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
85222 7764K fail2ban-HTTP  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
85222 7764K fail2ban-HTTP  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
 137K   16M fail2ban-BadBots  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
   82  7136 fail2ban-sasl  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,587,143,220,993,110,995
   82  7136 fail2ban-postfix  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,587
 137K   16M fail2ban-apache-overflows  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
 137K   16M fail2ban-apache-noscript  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
16620 1181K fail2ban-ssh-ddos  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
16621 1181K fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       XX.XX.XX.XX         0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 6649 packets, 5149K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain fail2ban-BadBots (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 137K   16M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-HTTP (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 170K   16M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-apache-noscript (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 137K   16M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-apache-overflows (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 137K   16M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-postfix (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   82  7136 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-sasl (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   82  7136 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
16621 1181K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-ssh-ddos (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
16620 1181K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-xmlrpc (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

and here's the `iptables -S` output:

```
$ sudo iptables -S

-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N fail2ban-BadBots
-N fail2ban-HTTP
-N fail2ban-apache-noscript
-N fail2ban-apache-overflows
-N fail2ban-postfix
-N fail2ban-sasl
-N fail2ban-ssh
-N fail2ban-ssh-ddos
-N fail2ban-xmlrpc
-A INPUT -s XX.XX.XX.XX/32 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j fail2ban-xmlrpc
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j fail2ban-HTTP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j fail2ban-HTTP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j fail2ban-BadBots
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587,143,220,993,110,995 -j fail2ban-sasl
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -j fail2ban-postfix
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j fail2ban-apache-overflows
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j fail2ban-apache-noscript
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh-ddos
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -s XX.XX.XX.XX/32 -j DROP
-A fail2ban-BadBots -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-HTTP -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-HTTP -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-apache-noscript -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-apache-overflows -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-postfix -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-sasl -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-ssh-ddos -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-xmlrpc -j RETURN
```

Additional fail2ban info: To be clear, fail2ban DOES modify the iptables rules, and send the emails. But the iptables rules don't seem to be working at all.

```
sudo fail2ban-client status
Status
|- Number of jail:      10
`- Jail list:   apache-badbots, apache-noscript, apache-overflows, http-get-dos, http-post-dos, postfix, sasl, ssh, ssh-ddos, xmlrpc

sudo fail2ban-client get http-get-dos actions
The jail http-get-dos has the following actions:
iptables, sendmail-buffered
```

Comment: what you have described and your rules should work, so we need to determine what you did not tell us. Is IPV6 disabled or is there any chance of an IPV6 route to your web pages. Do you have any nat table rules?

Comment: This is an AWS EC2 instance behind a classic AWS load balancer. It is the only instance connected to the load balancer. I see the IPV4 address when connecting to the server from my "banned" machine. The apache logs get the connecting host's IP address, not the load balancers address. There should not be any NAT going on with that server.

Comment: can you add the fail2ban conf ?

Comment: fail2ban-client status

Comment: fail2ban-client get <JAIL> actions

Comment: Sure, I'll add those things. BUT, my DROP rules don't work. I think there is a more fundamental problem that would also explain why the fail2ban rules aren't working

Comment: Suggest running tcpdump (or wireshark, if you prefer) to monitor traffic from/to XX.XX.XX.XX and correlate with packet counters in your rule set. Do `sudo tcpdump -n -tttt -i enp2s0 host XX.XX.XX.XX` replace the interface name with whatever yours is, or just leave it out.